# Regarding ImageView Orientation

Tags: android, android-intent

Using intent i captured an image into imageview, but on set it rotates either 90 or 270 . how to restrict this rotation?

```
Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                           i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.parse("file:///"+mProfile_Image));
startActivityForResult(i, 1);                                       

// Set to imageview

mProfileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file:///"+mProfile_Image));


// here imageview is the path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to restrict the rotation.

Try the following

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
        String imagePath = path;

        int rotate = 0;
// initializing
    int dpWidth = 100;
    int dpHeight = 100;
        try {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dpWidth = (int) ((outMetrics.widthPixels / density) * .75);

        dpHeight = (int) ((outMetrics.heightPixels / density) * .75);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
```

This will help you show the correct image

**Edit**

This code is not used to rotate the image permanently. So whenever you want to show image in inmageView just rotate and add.

**Edit 1**

Use this to set image in imageview

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: No it is not needed for you. I just add a piece of code in my project so copy that too leave that.

Comment: while setting into imageview , it again rotates

Comment: Ok what is the issue now.

Comment: Use this code when you want to add image in imageview.

Comment: captured in one orientation but display rotated by say 90 or 270 degree. if i captured in portrait mode, it display either 90 or 270 degree

Comment: which code code should i use to set image to imageview?  ??

Comment: My last comment will help. Do you still have problem?

Comment: Hi, On saving to sd card the orientation of image changes.. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Set orientation of your activity to portrait and give it a try.

```
<activity 
        android:name="YourActivityName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```